# AngularJS with ui-select error - Error: [ui.select:transcluded] Expected 1 ui-select-matchbut got 0

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"> Ticket Closure Type </label>
    <ui-select ng-model="resCode" theme="bootstrap"
               ng-click="vm.getClosureTypeOfCloseTicket(resCode)">
        <ui-select-choices ng-repeat="resolutionCode in resolutionCodes | filter: $select.search">
           {{resolutionCode.csmClosureReasonCode}}
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>

    <!-- <select ng-model="resCode" on-select="vm.getClosureTypeOfCloseTicket(resCode)">
        <option repeat="resolutionCode in resolutionCodes">{{resolutionCode.csmClosureReasonCode}}</option>
    </select> -->

</div>
```

The code piece I commented out is working as intended. On the other hand when I want to use ui-select, it gives the error below.

Error: [ui.select:transcluded] Expected 1 ui-select-match but got 0

Comment: What version of ui-select are you using?

Comment: @KScandrett 0.19.6

Comment: I wonder if it could also be your filter `filter: $select.search` I suggest you try removing that

Comment: Unfortunately removing that also did not solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to append ui-select-match directive to ui-select.

```
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select person...">{{$item.name}} &lt;{{$item.email}}&gt;</ui-select-match>
```

add something like above according to your need.

Answer (score 2):

Add classes of the same name to `ui-select-match` and `ui-select-choices`.

Source: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/218#issuecomment-292962397

& https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/1325#issuecomment-160922087

Comment: I tested using this plunk http://next.plnkr.co/edit/ZgqS05zgSgoEpvmks6io?p=preview&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=worker&utm_campaign=next&preview.  It's using a different version to your ui-select, but you may find it still resolves the problem.  Officially they say it was fixed in ui-select v0.14.3+, but other comments suggest it was found broken again

Answer (score 0):

Add the `tagging` attribute binded to a function that return `null`

HTML:

```
<ui-select ... tagging="tagHandler" ... >
```

JS:

```
$scope.tagHandler = function (tag){
    return null;
}
```